# send/receive an instance of a class in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

There are several basic MPI datatypes however, what if it is needed to send/receive an instance of a class. If this is possible, could you give an example?

Comment: Stanford is currently teaching a course on MPI. Some of the later lectures discuss how this is done: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cme194/cgi-bin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a `struct`, you may use `MPI_Type_create_struct` http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Type_create_struct.html

Here is an example of how to do so :

http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Type_create_struct.html

Bye,